# Archiving Oracle table data after a particular period of time

Tags: database, oracle, backup, archiving

We have a requirement of archiving data in an oracle table, older than 6 months into a flat file or a db log automatically.

Is there a existing way oracle addresses this issue or we need to do some manual work for this?

Also can anyone suggest the different ways of addressing this archiving process like writing a batch program to fetch the records greater than 6 months and write it to a flat file or csv etc. Either it can be oracle backed solution like triggers, scheduled jobs or programmatic solutions(preferably in java)

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to archive data into a flat file. Consider to use partitioning of your tables. Differnet partitions can be stored in different tablespaces and thus also on different storages (even a tape storage would be possible in theory).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Oracle 12c ILM for this [About Oracle Database for ILM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17613/part_lifecycle.htm#VLDBG1284)
It enables you to declare which data should be moved to a cheaper storage tier, or be purged.

This - of course - can also be achieved by custom code, moving partitions to dedicated tablespaces that have their datafiles on cheaper storage. It would be cheaper and easier to upgrade to 12c and use what Oracle created for that purpose. My vote would go for using the Oracle ILM tools; don't underestimate the development and maintenance effort for own code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is there any other way of addressing it just with oracle 10g installation alone.. Like triggers, scheduled jobs in oracle etc.

Comment: Sure, you can do this all by yourself but upgrading to a more recent Oracle version does give you quite some benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Perform following steps consider Partitioning licensing cost as an extra burden and don't need to query archived data after archiving.

1. Take a dump(expdp) for the archiving rows using query option which will provides 6 months old data set. [Reference](http://shaharear.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-query-parameter-in-expdpimpdp.html) for the query based expdp command.
2. Delete archived rows from the table.
3. Refresh statistics(dbms_stats) for the table to address performance issue in the future.

Note: You may need to offload table (backup table and restore again) or enable row movement for data which are not archived, it avoids issue of fragmentation and space unnecessary occupied by the table.